# Optimizations during xslt processing of template using XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xalan, oxygenxml

We use xslt 1.0 with Xpath 1.0 and XalanJ 2.7.1.
We make profiling of our templates and try to reduce the call time. So out biggest hotspot is:

```
<xsl:template name="tplAttribute">
    <xsl:param name="sourceObject" />
    <xsl:param name="sourceName" />
    <xsl:param name="targetName" />

    <xsl:variable name="sourceAttribute" select="$sourceObject/attribute[@name = $sourceName]" />
    <xsl:if test="$sourceAttribute">
        <dcx:attribute name="{$targetName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sourceAttribute" />
        </attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The average time during 871 hits is 103 and for variable 59ms.

Is there any better solution in order to reduce the time of the transformation?

**Edit:**
Input structure template calls when process 'sourceObject':

```
object
  tplAttribute 
  tplAttribute
  tplAttributeDefault
  tplAttribute
  tplAttributeSomeDifferentLogic
  tplAttribute
  tplAttributeOther
```

[image]

Comment: How many "attribute" elements would typically be found as children of $sourceObject?

Comment: Depends but from 20 to 100. So we have $sourceObject and in it we have to find a specific attribute in it. But then we have to search for another and so on. In some situations we have different logic - tplAttributeOther etc. So I am not sure does the creation of the variable slows the process or if we have two selects instead of sourceAttribute var will be faster based on the processor optimizations?

Comment: I don't know the internals of Xalan. Saxon-EE will probably create an index to evaluate this one - give it a try and let us know the results.

Comment: In our organization we can not use Saxon-EE because of the license. I can try with Oxigen but the result will not be useful for me(probably I will regret that we do not use Saxon :)

Answer (score 0):

Define a key `<xsl:key name="att-by-name" match="attribute" use="@name"/>` and then use

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sourceObject">
  <xsl:if test="key('att-by-name', $sourceName)">
            <dcx:attribute name="{$targetName}">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('att-by-name', $sourceName)" />
            </attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

instead of

```
    <xsl:variable name="sourceAttribute" select="$sourceObject/attribute[@name = $sourceName]" />
    <xsl:if test="$sourceAttribute">
        <dcx:attribute name="{$targetName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sourceAttribute" />
        </attribute>
    </xsl:if>
```

You might need to show us the exact structure of the document with sourceObject, the key based approach as shown will work if the `name` attribute of `attribute` elements identifies the `attribute` element(s) you are looking for in the complete document. If you are only looking into a subtree then you might need to include an id in the key value.